# Ubuntu cannot install npm

Tags: ubuntu, npm, apt

I have problem installing `npm` with `apt-get`. See the log below:

```
matej@matej-Inspiron-7720:~$ sudo apt-get install npm
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  libaudclient2 libid3tag0 libimlib2 libxmmsclient6 linux-headers-3.16.0-39 linux-headers-3.16.0-39-generic linux-headers-generic
  linux-image-3.16.0-39-generic linux-image-extra-3.16.0-39-generic linux-image-generic rlwrap thermald
Use 'apt-get autoremove' to remove them.
The following extra packages will be installed:
  gyp javascript-common libc-ares-dev libjs-node-uuid libjs-underscore libssl-dev libssl-doc libv8-3.14-dev node-abbrev node-ansi node-ansi-color-table
  node-archy node-async node-block-stream node-combined-stream node-cookie-jar node-delayed-stream node-forever-agent node-form-data node-fstream
  node-fstream-ignore node-github-url-from-git node-glob node-graceful-fs node-gyp node-inherits node-ini node-json-stringify-safe node-lockfile
  node-lru-cache node-mime node-minimatch node-mkdirp node-mute-stream node-node-uuid node-nopt node-normalize-package-data node-npmlog node-once node-osenv
  node-qs node-read node-read-package-json node-request node-retry node-rimraf node-semver node-sha node-sigmund node-slide node-tar node-tunnel-agent
  node-underscore node-which nodejs-dev
Suggested packages:
  node-hawk node-aws-sign node-oauth-sign node-http-signature
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  gyp javascript-common libc-ares-dev libjs-node-uuid libjs-underscore libssl-dev libssl-doc libv8-3.14-dev node-abbrev node-ansi node-ansi-color-table
  node-archy node-async node-block-stream node-combined-stream node-cookie-jar node-delayed-stream node-forever-agent node-form-data node-fstream
  node-fstream-ignore node-github-url-from-git node-glob node-graceful-fs node-gyp node-inherits node-ini node-json-stringify-safe node-lockfile
  node-lru-cache node-mime node-minimatch node-mkdirp node-mute-stream node-node-uuid node-nopt node-normalize-package-data node-npmlog node-once node-osenv
  node-qs node-read node-read-package-json node-request node-retry node-rimraf node-semver node-sha node-sigmund node-slide node-tar node-tunnel-agent
  node-underscore node-which nodejs-dev npm
0 upgraded, 56 newly installed, 0 to remove and 2 not upgraded.
1 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 2054 kB/3345 kB of archives.
After this operation, 15,2 MB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
WARNING: The following packages cannot be authenticated!
  gyp javascript-common libjs-node-uuid libjs-underscore libssl-dev libssl-doc libv8-3.14-dev node-async node-node-uuid node-underscore libc-ares-dev
  node-abbrev node-ansi node-ansi-color-table node-archy node-inherits node-block-stream node-delayed-stream node-combined-stream node-cookie-jar
  node-forever-agent node-mime node-form-data node-rimraf node-mkdirp node-graceful-fs node-fstream node-lru-cache node-sigmund node-minimatch
  node-fstream-ignore node-github-url-from-git node-once node-glob nodejs-dev node-nopt node-npmlog node-osenv node-tunnel-agent node-json-stringify-safe
  node-qs node-request node-semver node-tar node-which node-gyp node-ini node-lockfile node-mute-stream node-normalize-package-data node-read
  node-read-package-json node-retry node-sha node-slide npm
Install these packages without verification? [y/N] y
Err http://si.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ utopic-updates/main libssl-dev amd64 1.0.1f-1ubuntu9.8
  404  Not Found [IP: 193.2.1.88 80]
Err http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ utopic-security/main libssl-dev amd64 1.0.1f-1ubuntu9.8
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.149 80]
Err http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ utopic-security/main libssl-doc all 1.0.1f-1ubuntu9.8
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.149 80]
E: Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/o/openssl/libssl-dev_1.0.1f-1ubuntu9.8_amd64.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.149 80]

E: Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/o/openssl/libssl-doc_1.0.1f-1ubuntu9.8_all.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.149 80]

E: Unable to fetch some archives, maybe run apt-get update or try with --fix-missing?
```

Comment: This question belongs on http://askubuntu.com/

Answer (score 0):

The NodeJS package includes npm.

How to install via package-manager:

```
   $ curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_4.x | sudo -E bash -
   $ sudo apt-get install -y nodejs
   $ sudo ln -s "$(which nodejs)" /usr/bin/node
```

Optional: install build tools

To compile and install native addons from npm you may also need to install build tools:

```
   $ sudo apt-get install -y build-essential
```

Source: https://nodejs.org/en/download/package-manager/

I hope helped you